# Sample OSGI project for RESTful web service using spring-3

Tags: spring, rest, osgi, jpa-2.0

I need a sample project of OSGI which creates RESTful Web service using spring framework and JPA persistence project.
I have tried creating project with these but i guess i am doing something wrong.. i tried a lot to find the solutions to those exceptions but failed..

Comment: Have you explored some of the FuseSource archetypes? Not sure if they cover JPA, but you should at least be able to get a CXF JAX-RS one built for OSGi. JPA is a different layer altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OSGi RemoteServices with [Apache CXF DOSGi](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html). You can check very nice [blog article with JPA/JAX-RS/DOSGi](http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/about/eclipse_spring/eclipse_spring_dosgi/).